# Adding line break or new line in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, wcf

This may be a pretty noob question but I am not able to figure out after repeated trial and error.

I have a string getting returned from wcf service like this

> TVA Rate cannot be less that 1 or greater than 49.-----
>    L'âge du permis doit être inférieur à l'âge du conducteur moins 17 ans

What I want is in my ajax success when I get this message I would replace the ----- portion with a new line so that these two lines get displayed on separate lines.

What I have done for this

Try 1

```
if (response.data.Messages.Messages != null) {                        
    $scope.warningMsg = response.data.Messages.Messages[0].EventSource.replace("------", "</br>");
}
```

Try 2

```
if (response.data.Messages.Messages != null) {                        
    $scope.warningMsg = response.data.Messages.Messages[0].EventSource.replace("------", "\n");
}
```

And the WCF message is getting constructed in this way

```
if (data.DriverData.age - data.DriverData.permitage < 18)
{
    isValid = false;
    validationMsg.Append("------");
    validationMsg.Append("L'âge du permis doit être inférieur à l'âge du conducteur moins 17 ans.");               
}
if (data.RCData.YearsProvenWithAttest > 5)
{
    isValid = false;
    validationMsg.Append("------");
    validationMsg.Append("YearsProvenWithAttest MAX 5.");               
}
```

No matter I see the result in single sentence always.

Can someone please tell me what silly thing I am doing?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe put the parts of the message in separate block-formatted elements, or (more simply) put a `<br>` between them. *edit* it's `<br>` not `</br>` - `</br>` is meaningless in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change `</br>` to `<br />`

That should give you the line breaks where you need them.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry the output is `TVA Rate cannot be less that 1 or greater than 49.<br />L'âge du permis doit être inférieur à l'âge du conducteur moins 17 ans.`

Answer (score 1):

What are you doing with the message? If you're appending it to .innerText, you'll see exactly the characters you add. Use .innerHTML to see the html.

Comment: I do ng-bind with the scope variable.